# JS "upgrade" patterns

Tags: javascript, local-storage, upgrade

Are there any patterns for cases when something (in my case it's a filters) is stored on client (e.g. `localStorage`) and you need to run a script once per user/version to migrate data you store. For example, initially there is a filter saved in `localStorage` with a key `myFilter` after some time you decide that you need to separate filters per environment, so you need separate `dev-myFilter`, `train-myFilter`, etc. You update your code to work with environment-dependant filters, but there are users who have old `myFilter` and you want with next deployed version to run script which will update the key of saved filter if there is one.

Question is - what are patterns/best practices for that?

Comment: If the data is in flux, then it may be prudent NOT to use localStorage..

Comment: @Pogrindis I'm using Redux and for the initial state it checks the localStorage and uses it if there is something set. Why it's prudent NOT to use localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "best practices", but the obvious technical solution, just like with any API or storage format, is to store a version number alongside the data. If you didn't do so from the start, assume version == 1 when absent.

You may be able to avoid this if the data structure is *so* unique between versions that the version can be determined simply by examining it.

Either way, you simply perform the translation whenever you spot that the user's data is in the old format.

The downside of this is that you have to keep checking; for a web application this is unlikely to be a bottleneck, but if you can make your data forward-compatible from the outset then you may save a bit of processing time on each request. But for the data to be useful you've got to read it anyway, so a little branching for as long as you wish to maintain backward-compatibility is, again, unlikely to be a big problem.

Comment: I don't like running the check every time, besides there could be several version difference + several data structures with versioning, then it would get messy. I was thinking of a separate file where you specify - for this version we run this script which will transform data accordingly, but still there is a problem when user missed some upgrades and you can't upgrade from v1 to v8 straightforward - you need to do it step-by-step and so have to run these checks every time :(